# Secret agent escapes straightjacket using hot coffee

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this 2 volume (there might be more than 2) comic book when I was a kid (around 1990, possibly before)

It starred a secret agent that was up against some evil dictator/Junta-general that farmed cacti to use for some glue/sticky weapon.

It featured some unrealistic technology, but the setting was contemporary (around 1980-90)

The one sequence from the story that I am certain about was that our hero was captured and put in a straightjacket made from the glue mentioned above, and then "tortured" by being unable to reach some cakes coming out from a machine. He escapes by crawling under some flowing hot coffee that dissolves the straightjacket.

Any ideas/links to the title/author or some images from the comicbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was "Steve contre Dr. Yes" by Jacques Devos.

Danish version description here: https://comicwiki.dk/wiki/Steve_kontra_dr._Yes?fbclid=IwAR3-y7FhkiOs2zDUdW-pD2-Ka3CxPHfGjQ52NAVlwtvS5zH5U_Vt44p4aCU

Comment: How evil! Cakes that you can't reach, omg. I'd surrender my secret knowledge immediately (but I'm very fat and greedy)